# Can anyone explain this please "In HTML, the computer can interpret raw text that is wrapped in HTML elements"

Tags: html

I am sorry to ask such a lame question, I am very new to the HTML. I understood the words but not able to understand them in the sentence.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: i asume it means if you put text not inside the right element, such as `<h1>` or other simular elements, the browser will still render them as text on the site, instead of giving an error when you place text in the wrong spot in forexample `php` then you get an error and it stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take that to mean that a computer takes everything written between opening and closing HTML elements and displays that raw text according to the HTML element.

For example:

```
<h1> This is my header </h1>
```

Would display the text as a heading size one.

## This is my header

Maybe I am being too simplistic.